# A couple of rate changing problems that I do not know how to do

Tags: calculus

**1.**

A trough is 10 ft long and its ends have the shape of isosceles triangles that are 3 ft across at the top and have a height of 1 ft. If the trough is being filled with water at a rate of 12 $ft^3$/min, how fast is the water level rising when the water is 6 inches deep?

*Answer Attempt:*

I'm confused at the diagram here and how to solve it. Help?

**2.**

A kite 100 ft above the ground moves horizontally at a speed of 8 ft/s. At what rate is the angle between the string and the horizontal decreasing when 200 ft of string has been let out?

*Answer attempt*

can someone help me with this? I'm not sure of the diagram that I need to draw and how to solve it.

Comment: The key to problem 1. is computing the volume of water when the height is $h.$  Can you do that?  Similarly, in problem 2 you have have to be able to compute the and when $s$ feet of string have been let out.  In general, in problems of this sort, the first thing to do is to get a formula for the quantity whose derivative you will have to compute, in term of the data at hand.

Comment: A trough would be in the shape of an upside down isosceles triangular prism

Answer (score 1):

## 1.

When the height in the trough is h what is the width of the water.
$$\frac{h}{b}=\frac{1}{3}\implies b=3h $$
Using this we can calculate that at height $h$ the volume is $$V=\frac12bhl=\frac32h^2l$$
Here $l$ is the length of the trough. We must now find what is $dh/dt$ given we know $dV/dt$
$$\frac{dV}{dt}=3hl\frac{dh}{dt}$$
Now put values for $dV/dt=12$, $h=6$ and $l=10$.

## 2.

Here we much calculate what is the angle. When kite is $x$ meters away. This makes a right triangle with height $h$ and base $x$, the angle $\theta$ is given by $$\theta=\tan ^{-1} \left(\frac{h}{x}\right)$$
We should now be able to calculate $d\theta/dt$. $$\frac{d\theta}{dt}=\frac{1}{1+(\frac{h}{x})^2}\cdot\frac{-h}{x^2}\frac{dx}{dt}$$

Comment: how do you know the triangles are similar again? By the shared angle and what else?

Comment: Can it be solved without converting b to h?

Comment: No, at some point you will have to make that conversion doing it in the beginning is the best time

Comment: For 2, we just solve for x using Pythagorean theorum right?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: Did you get 0.3555555?

Comment: If you put the right formula and values. Check it again and if you get same then it is correct.